# Get Date from Jtextfield and add expire Date

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I have a Date in a JtextField "11-06-2016"
I want to get it back to DateFormat (11-07-2016) and add 1 Month Time for an expiry Date.
So I can get the following
Start Date : 11-06-2016
End Date : 11-07-2016

I tried the following

```
public static String expireDate(String Data)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    java.util.Date textFieldAsDate = null;
        try {
            textFieldAsDate = sdf.parse(Data);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cal.setTime(textFieldAsDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        sdf.format(cal.getTime());
      return sdf.toString();
}
```

This is the current Output
java.text.SimpleDateFormat@9586200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please replace following line:

```
return sdf.toString();
```

by this line:

```
return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

and tell me the result?

Comment: Worked as intended, I actually tried that before, but I hadnt fixed the code behind it and never gave it a try again. =) thank you for the help